# How can i open file in MS access which is created by asp.net in .mdb format

Tags: c#

How can i export gridview  in MS Access?

I am using this code

```
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.Buffer = true;
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Details.mdb"));
 Response.ContentType = "application/ms-access";
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
 DataGrid dGrid = new DataGrid();
 dGrid.AllowPaging = false;
 dGrid.DataSource = dt;
 dGrid.DataBind();
 dGrid.RenderControl(htw);
 Response.Write(sw.ToString());
 Response.End();
```

but by this code file not open in MS access
What should i do?

Comment: it shows error or something else

Comment: Even if you succeed in serving the MDB file, do you understand that this will download a local copy of the MDB file? This won't make the MDB file work "shared".

Answer (score -1):

I use below code for  open MS access Database using C#:

enter code here

```
    ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
    ADOX.Table table = new ADOX.Table();


    table.Name = "Table1";
    table.Columns.Append("PartNumber", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 6); 
    table.Columns.Append("AnInteger", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, 10); 
    try
    {
        cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=d:/m2.accdb;" + "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");
        cat.Tables.Append(table);
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;" + "Data Source=d:/m2.accdb");
       conn.Open();

             OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
             cmd.Connection = conn;

             cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1
```

([PartNumber],[AnInteger]) VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName)";

```
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName",
```

OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "neha";

```
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName",
```

OleDbType.VarChar).Value = 20;

```
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();                                 

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    cat = null;
```